# How to repopulate checkboxes in form on refresh AND post the form values to page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using an ajax script to repopulate checkboxes on a page when the page refreshes or is sent to another page and then back again.  The script works fine as the checkboxes will still be checked after page refresh.

The problem I have is these checkboxes work as filters.  So when clicked it POSTS to the page and my php script puts each value into a string for my query.  When a page is refreshed the checkboxes stay checked but are not posting the values to the page.  How can I make this Ajax script POST the values of the form after it repopulates my checked checkboxes on page refresh?

Here is Ajax script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function handleButtonClick(button){
    if ($(button).text().match("Check all")){
      $(":checkbox").prop("checked", true)
    } else {
      $(":checkbox").prop("checked", false)
    };
    updateButtonStatus();
  }

  function updateButtonStatus(){
    var allChecked = $(":checkbox").length === $(":checkbox:checked").length;
    $("button").text(allChecked? "Uncheck all" : "Check all");
  }

  function updateCookie(){
    var elementValues = {};
    $(":checkbox").each(function(){
      elementValues[this.id] = this.checked;
    });

    elementValues["buttonText"] = $("button").text();
    $.cookie('elementValues', elementValues, { expires: 7, path: '/' })
  }

  function repopulateFormELements(){
    var elementValues = $.cookie('elementValues');
    if(elementValues){
      Object.keys(elementValues).forEach(function(element) {
        var checked = elementValues[element];
        $("#" + element).prop('checked', checked);
      });

      $("button").text(elementValues["buttonText"])
    }
  }

  $(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
    updateButtonStatus();
    updateCookie();
  });

  $("button").on("click", function() {
    handleButtonClick(this);
    updateCookie();
  });

  $.cookie.json = true;
  repopulateFormELements();


</script>
```

And the PHP on same page that puts what is checked into a string for my query

```
if (isset($_POST["2kandunder"])) {
$arguments[] = "AND `2kandunder` = 'yes'";
}
if (isset($_POST["2kto4k"])) {
$arguments[] = "AND `2kto4k` = 'yes'";
}
if (isset($_POST["4kandup"])) {
$arguments[] = "AND 4kandup = 'yes'";
}

if(!empty($arguments)) {
$str = implode($arguments);
}
```

And html form

```
 <form id="form" method="post" action="">
<input type="checkbox" name="2kandunder" class="checkbox" id="1" onchange="$('#form').submit();" <?=(isset($_POST['2kandunder'])?' checked':'')?>/> $2000 And Under   

<input type="checkbox" name="2kto4k" class="checkbox" id="2" onchange="$('#form').submit();" <?=(isset($_POST['2kto4k'])?' checked':'')?>/> $2001 To $4000

<input type="checkbox" name="4kandup"  class="checkbox" id="3" onchange="$('#form').submit();" <?=(isset($_POST['4kandup'])?' checked':'')?>/> $4001 And Up
```

I have tried adding the following to my ajax but I am totally new to ajax and it was a total guess.  This code makes the page start blinking and the page will go to "page not found" after about 5 seconds.

```
$('#form').submit();
```

Comment: Just access the created cookies in PHP with `$_COOKIE['elementValues']` to rebuild the filter on page load

Comment: @darkbee Thanks for reply.  This would be perfect if I could get it to work.  I echoed $_COOKIE['elementValues'] and it displays this:  "2kandunder":true,"2kto4k":false,"4kandup":false.  So I added this to my php: if ($_COOKIE["2kandunder"]=true) {
  $arguments[] = "AND `2kandunder` = 'yes'";
  }  Am I on the right track?  This puts it into the string but it is always in the query no matter if it is "false" or true".  Can you maybe show me a quick example of how to add that to my existing if(isset($_POST php?

Comment: Your javascript works fine if placed after the body close tag or within `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: @manta  Sorry for my ignorance but Im not sure I follow.  Are you saying the $('#form').submit(); should work if placed properly?  I have the ajax (at least I think its ajax) script just after the closing body tag.  I tried to add the $('#form').submit(); right after the repopulateFormELements(); to try and get it to submit my form but it causes the page to blink and go to "page not found".  I don't really know anything about the $(document).ready() and cant find that in the existing ajax script I have?

Comment: working fiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/xyd8-9e6g

Comment: Thanks @manta for that it works perfect now! One more question if you don't mind.  It works perfect on page refresh and when it leaves the page and comes back.  But I am trying to add pagination to my results.  Once I click on next or page 2 the checkbox is still checked but is not posting checked checkbox to the string like it does on page refresh.  What exactly is happening when I click to go to next set of results with pagination isn't it just refreshing the page which new set of results?

Comment: @manta This is not true. In fact OP is not even using ajax

Comment: @DarkBee Stating the obvious is a requirement? If that were true, would we solve anything? Id rather not be dissecting every aspect of a question to find a simple answer. You have a problem with the question, why not highlight that with the OP?

Comment: Unrelated: you should download and combine those JS files. 2 requests to 2 different servers is expensive.

Answer (score 0):

As you store the cookie, you can use it information in PHP as well to repopulate the query filter and the checkboxes on the form

```
<?php

    $checkboxes = array('checkbox1' => false, 'checkbox2' => false, 'checkbox3' => false, 'checkbox4' => false, );

    if (isset($_COOKIE['elementValues'])) {
        /* 
            Cookie values are stored like JSON
        */
        $raw = json_decode($_COOKIE['elementValues'], true); //cast to array
        var_dump($raw);
        foreach($raw as $input_name => $value) {
            if (isset($checkboxes[$input_name])) {
                $checkboxes[$input_name] = $value; //true/false
            }
        }
    }

    var_dump($checkboxes);


    if (isset($_POST["checkbox1"]) || $checkboxes['checkbox1']) {
        $arguments[] = "AND `2kandunder` = 'yes'";
    }
    if (isset($_POST["checkbox2"]) || $checkboxes['checkbox2']) {
        $arguments[] = "AND `2kto4k` = 'yes'";
    }
    if (isset($_POST["checkbox3"]) || $checkboxes['checkbox3']) {
        $arguments[] = "AND 4kandup = 'yes'";
    }

    $str = '';
    if(!empty($arguments)) {
        $str = implode(' ',$arguments);
    }

    echo 'QUERY FILTER : ' . $str;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Checkbox state - Coookies</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="POST">
            <?php
                foreach($checkboxes as $input_name => $checked) {
                    echo '<input type="checkbox" id="'.$input_name.'" name="'.$input_name.'"'.($checked?' checked':'').' />';
                }
            ?>
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>


        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>        
        <script>
          function handleButtonClick(button){
            if ($(button).text().match("Check all")){
              $(":checkbox").prop("checked", true)
            } else {
              $(":checkbox").prop("checked", false)
            };
            updateButtonStatus();
          }

          function updateButtonStatus(){
            var allChecked = $(":checkbox").length === $(":checkbox:checked").length;
            $("button").text(allChecked? "Uncheck all" : "Check all");
          }

          function updateCookie(){
            var elementValues = {};
            $(":checkbox").each(function(){
              elementValues[this.id] = this.checked;
            });

            elementValues["buttonText"] = $("button").text();
            $.cookie('elementValues', elementValues, { expires: 7, path: '/' })
          }

          $(":checkbox").on("change", function(){
            updateButtonStatus();
            updateCookie();
          });

          $("button").on("click", function() {
            handleButtonClick(this);
            updateCookie();
          });

          $.cookie.json = true;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```